# How to set up a recurring payment

Tags: 8, commerce, payment-gateways

I need to set up a recurring payment on Drupal 8. I discovered these two possiblity :

- https://stripe.com/us/billing
- https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring

What is the difference between these two possiblity ?

The commerce reccuring module looks extremely complex to set up.

Comment: It really comes down to whether or not you want to maintain recurring billing yourself within Drupal, or outsource it.  Outsourcing it to Recurly, say, allows for multiple payment methods such as Stripe, but you can also add other ones (or remove them) there without having to do much work on your Drupal site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's entirely dependent on your business needs. The advantage of Commerce Recurring is that as part of the Drupal Commerce ecosystem, it gives you a complete toolset for building a subscription management interface in Drupal 8. This will let you completely customize the checkout flow, order receipts, other user interfaces and more, but it does require experience with Drupal 8 to build and maintain. For more information, review the documentation at:

https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/recurring

If you just want to embed a Stripe widget, I recommend [MoonClerk](https://www.moonclerk.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Recurly module](https://www.drupal.org/project/recurly) to integrate the Recurly subscription service.

This module has a stable release for Drupal 8.

The project page also has a fair amount of information on PCI compliance.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Stripe Registration module](https://www.drupal.org/project/stripe_registration), which implements [Stripe Plans](https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans).

It has the important limitation of "one subscription per user".